# Using Python to Stop and disable remote server services

Tags: python, eclipse, remote-server

I new to programming and the Python world and am seeking help and guidance.

I am trying to write code to stop and disable windows services during maintenance. I want to disable a service to avoid any restart during maintenance window.

I am able to stop it if I use "Net stop service" but when I use command "SC \servername stop " it is not working. Below is my code.

This code is working fine with Net command but error when I replace same command with "SC \servername stop "

```
    #Connection and Service change code    
     connection= wmi.WMI(line, user=username, password=password)
     process_startup = connection.Win32_ProcessStartup.new()
     command='Net stop spooler' #Works but error cmd "SC \\servername stop 
     <service>" error
     command5= "Net start spooler" #works error in "SC \\servername config 
     <service> start=disabled"
     if tasks=='stop':
       process__id2, result = 
       connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine=command, 
       ProcessStartupInformation=process_startup)
       process__id, result = 
       connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine=command5, 
       ProcessStartupInformation=process_startup)
       print("job disabled")'
```

Thank you for help

Comment: This is not valid Python code.

Comment: Except for some word wrapping, it will do fine.  It's not PEP8 compliant, but it looks OK if hard to read.  Reformatted for proper spacing and line endings:  https://gist.github.com/ascheel/63880800051123ff62aef428c6eb030c

Comment: @KlausD. I have just put some of the text and I do agree it is not in proper format. It works fine if I use "Net" command but gives error when use "SC" command.